# Serialize select

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

My form (somewhere about)

```
<form name="ShoppingCart" method="post">
  <select name="city">
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567626">City1</option>
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567636">City2</option>
    ...
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567689">CityN</option>
  </select>
  <select name="warehouses">
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567329">Warehouses1</option>
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567452">Warehouses2</option>
    ...
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567352">WarehousesN</option>
  </select>
  <div>
      <input class="submit_form" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Select warehouses created dynamically depending on the choice of the first select. 
I need `serialize()` form so that it is present value and text in serialize.

`cityName=City1&cityValue=db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567352&warehousesName=Warehouses1&warehousesValue=db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567352`

How can I do that ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are you getting now? Is something not working? Your form looks correct except the `name` attributes do not match up with what you described in your post data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're posting the Data, you can use an Object or your can use FormData. Either way you will need to build the new structure as your Form does not contain those items. Most would use the Value to find the data on the needed data server-side instead of sending it through to the server. Pass the smallest amount of data to the server as needed.

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fData = {};
    // Alternate:
    var formD = new FormData();

    $("select", this).each(function(i, el) {
      fData[$(el).attr("name") + "Name"] = $("option:selected", el).text().trim();
      fData[$(el).attr("name") + "Value"] = $(el).val();
      // Alternate:
      formD.append($(el).attr("name") + "Name", $("option:selected", el).text().trim());
      formD.append($(el).attr("name") + "Value", $(el).val());
    });
    console.log($.param(fData));
    // FormData does not have a Serialize or Stringify method
    for (var pair of formD.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="ShoppingCart" method="post">
  <select name="city">
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567626">City1</option>
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567636">City2</option>
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567689">CityN</option>
  </select>
  <select name="warehouses">
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567329">Warehouses1</option>
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567452">Warehouses2</option>
    <option value="db5c88c4-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567352">WarehousesN</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <input class="submit_form" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, this iterates over the `select` elements and collects the data as you desired. You then need to post it to your script.

Comment: Note that you could use `$.param(fData)` to get the exact format the OP asks for